# Text in long multirow is not vertically centered

Tags: tables, rotating, multirow

I have a large table, and the first two cells are multirow cells which span the height of the table.  Instead of centering properly, they are centered in the top portion of the table, and I am completely confused by this behaviour.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multirow}                               % Layout options - tables
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}             % Layout options - tables
\usepackage{rotating}                               % Rotate objects
\usepackage{array}                              % formatting tables fix
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}       % formatting tables fix

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{m{5mm} m{5mm}| p{25mm}  p{5mm} p{55mm}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\multirow{8}{5mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Uncentered text and arrow}} & \multirow{8}{5mm}{$\downarrow$} & A B C & \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{It may be that the primal source of all}\\
&&\hspace*{10mm}\underbar{D} \newline \newline $ \hspace*{20mm}\nwarrow$ & \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{those pictorial delusions will be found }\\ 
&&& \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{among the oldest Hindoo, Egyptian, and }\\
&& E& \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{Grecian sculptures. For ever since those }\\
&& F,G,\newline H  \newline I,J    & $\downarrow$ & inventive but unscrupulous times when on the\\ 
&& K & $\leftarrow$ &   marble panellings of temples, the pedestals\\ 
&&L& &\\
&& \multicolumn{3}{C{90mm}}{ of statues, and on shields, medallions, cups, and coins, the dolphin was drawn in  scales of chain-armor like Saladin's, and  a helmeted head like St. George's; ever since then has something of the same sort of license prevailed, not only in most popular pictures of the whale, but in many scientific presentations of him. }\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end {tabular}

\end{document}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image: miktex output]

So, my question is, why is it centering high, and how can I fix it?

Thank-you

Comment: Here is an even more interesting question.  I put the entire tabular inside \settoheight and got 148.66034pt, which is far smaller than the tabular.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a proper fix, but manually adjusting the first optional argument of `\multirow` you get:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multirow}                               % Layout options - tables
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,caption}             % Layout options - tables
\usepackage{rotating}                               % Rotate objects
\usepackage{array}                              % formatting tables fix
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}       % formatting tables fix

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{5pt}
\begin{tabular}{m{5mm} m{5mm}| p{25mm}  p{5mm} p{55mm}}\toprule[1.5pt]
\multirow{8}[50]{5mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Uncentered text and arrow}} & \multirow{8}[50]{5mm}{$\downarrow$} & A B C & \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{It may be that the primal source of all}\\
&&\hspace*{10mm}\underbar{D} \newline \newline $ \hspace*{20mm}\nwarrow$ & \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{those pictorial delusions will be found }\\
&&& \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{among the oldest Hindoo, Egyptian, and }\\
&& E& \multicolumn{2}{C{60mm}}{Grecian sculptures. For ever since those }\\
&& F,G,\newline H  \newline I,J    & $\downarrow$ & inventive but unscrupulous times when on the\\
&& K & $\leftarrow$ &   marble panellings of temples, the pedestals\\
&&L& &\\
&& \multicolumn{3}{C{90mm}}{ of statues, and on shields, medallions, cups, and coins, the dolphin was drawn in  scales of chain-armor like Saladin's, and  a helmeted head like St. George's; ever since then has something of the same sort of license prevailed, not only in most popular pictures of the whale, but in many scientific presentations of him. }\\
\bottomrule[1.5pt]
\end {tabular}

\end{document}
```